# Скажите нубу почему память течет при перерисовке(внешний код вызывает setFields)

Tags: awt, java, swing

```
package ubertask;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Максим
 */
public class Drawer extends JPanel
{

    int NS1=1;    //Number of sids in first polygon
    int LS1=1;
    int X1=1;
    int Y1=1;
    double R1=1;

    int NS2=1;    
    int LS2=1;
    int X2=1;
    int Y2=1;
    double R2=1;

    int Xmax, Ymax, Xmin, Ymin;

    Polygon p1 = new Polygon();
    Polygon p2 = new Polygon();

    void Drawer()
    {
         //p1 = new Polygon();
         //p2 = new Polygon();
    }

    public void setFilds(int fNS1, 
    int fLS1,
    int fX1,
    int fY1,
    int fNS2,    
    int fLS2,
    int fX2,
    int fY2)
    {
        NS1 = fNS1; 
        LS1 = fLS1;
        X1 = fX1;
        Y1 = fY1;
        NS2 = fNS2; 
        LS2 = fLS2;
        X2 = fX2;
        Y2 = fY2;

        R1 =  LS1/(2*Math.sin(360/NS1/2/57.295779));
        R2 =  LS2/(2*Math.sin(360/NS2/2/57.295779));

        this.repaint();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {

         g.clearRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
         g.setColor(Color.black);

         double X1p = X1+(int)R1;
         double Y1p = Y1;
         double X1n = X1p;
         double Y1n = Y1p;

         Xmax = (int) X1p;
         Xmin = (int) X1p;
         Ymin = (int) Y1p;
         Ymax = (int) Y1p;

         p1.addPoint((int)X1n, (int) Y1n);
         for(int i=1; i!=NS1; i++)
         {

             X1n = (int) ( X1+(X1p-X1)*Math.cos(360/NS1/57.295779)-(Y1p-Y1)*Math.sin(360/NS1/57.295779) );  // знаю медлено
             Y1n = (int) ( Y1+(X1p-X1)*Math.sin(360/NS1/57.295779)+(Y1p-Y1)*Math.cos(360/NS1/57.295779) );

             g.drawLine((int)X1p, (int)Y1p, (int) X1n, (int)Y1n);
             X1p = X1n;
             Y1p = Y1n;    
             p1.addPoint((int)X1n, (int) Y1n);
             if(Xmax < X1n) { Xmax = (int) X1n; }
             if(Xmin > X1n) { Xmin = (int) X1n; }
             if(Ymax < Y1n) { Ymax = (int) Y1n; }
             if(Ymin > Y1n) { Ymin = (int) Y1n; }
         }
          X1n = X1+(int)R1;
          Y1n = Y1;

             g.drawLine((int)X1p,(int) Y1p,(int) X1n, (int) Y1n);
             X1p = X1n;
             Y1p = Y1n;

         double X2p = X2+(int)R2;
         double Y2p = Y2;
         double X2n = X2p;
         double Y2n = Y2p;

         p2.addPoint((int)X2n, (int) Y2n);
         if(Xmax < X2n) { Xmax = (int) X2n; }
         if(Xmin > X2n) { Xmin = (int) X2n; }
         if(Ymax < Y2n) { Ymax = (int) Y2n; }
         if(Ymin > Y2n) { Ymin = (int) Y2n; }

         for(int i=1; i!=NS2; i++)
         {

             X2n =  ( X2+(X2p-X2)*Math.cos(360/NS2/57.295779)-(Y2p-Y2)*Math.sin(360/NS2/57.295779) );  // знаю медлено
             Y2n =  ( Y2+(X2p-X2)*Math.sin(360/NS2/57.295779)+(Y2p-Y2)*Math.cos(360/NS2/57.295779) );

             g.drawLine((int)X2p, (int)Y2p, (int) X2n,(int) Y2n);
             X2p = X2n;
             Y2p = Y2n;

             p2.addPoint((int)X2n, (int) Y2n);

             if(Xmax < X2n) { Xmax = (int) X2n; }
             if(Xmin > X2n) { Xmin = (int) X2n; }
             if(Ymax < Y2n) { Ymax = (int) Y2n; }
             if(Ymin > Y2n) { Ymin = (int) Y2n; }
         }

          X2n = X2+(int)R2;
          Y2n = Y2;

             g.drawLine((int)X2p, (int)Y2p, (int) X2n, (int) Y2n);
             X2p = X2n;
             Y2p = Y2n;

             //System.out.println(Xmax+" "+Xmin+" "+Ymax+" "+Ymin);
             g.setColor(Color.green);
             for(int x=Xmin-20; x<Xmax+20; x++ )
                {
                  for(int y=Ymin-20; y<Ymax+20; y++ )
                     {
                      if( p1.contains(x, y))
                      {
                          if(p2.contains(x, y)) 
                          {
                              g.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
                          }
                      }
                     }
                }

             p1.reset();
             p2.reset();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Память не течет, Swing юзает событийную модель, т.е. где-то создается объект типа Event и помещается в очередь на обработку.
Сам объект "события" занимает место, а уничтожится он только когда скажет gc. 
В общем если Вы помониторите работу, ту скорее всего увидите что-то типа пилы, по занятой памяти. т.е. память будет заполнятся пока коллектор не решит ее освободить.
вот тут хорошая статья не по самому вопросу, но на многое глаза открывает :)
http://habrahabr.ru/post/112676/